# Convert anonymous user with Firebase: Cannot read property 'getAuthResponse' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using VueJS and Firebase Auth (NPM - Version 5.6.0). I need to convert an anonymous user into an registered user with Google as a provider. I tried the [recently updated sample from the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account):

```
        anonymousToGoogle: function () {
      var googleUser
      var provider
      var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token)
      firebase.auth.currentUser.linkWithRedirect(provider)
      firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function (usercred) {
        var user = usercred.user
        console.log('Anonymous account successfully upgraded', user)
      }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error upgrading anonymous account', error)
      })
    }
  }
```

Button (uses the VuetifyJS framework):

```
<v-btn block @click="anonymousToGoogle()">CONVERT - Login with Google</v-btn>
```

The console shows this error after clicking the button:

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'getAuthResponse' of undefined"

Comment: How do you set googleUser?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Good question, maybe the official Google Firebase docs are missing something? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account

Comment: What I mean is how do you get the value of `googleUser` within the `anonymousToGoogle` function? Either you would have it store in the Vue.js component and you would do something like `this.googleUser` or you have it in a Vuex store, or you should pass it as an argument of the function. But for the moment it seems it is not initialized, hence the error you get when you do `googleUser.getAuthResponse()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `linkWithRedirect` on the anonymous user.

```
// Assuming you previously signed in anonymously.
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(function(result) {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  // Page will redirect to google and then back. You can get back
  // result via getRedirectResult().
  return firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithRedirect(provider);
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Error occurred.
});
```

Comment: It works but I struggle to get the results via getRedirectResult(). This is my code:  https://pastebin.com/fSfTeBgs (sorry for the link - the code was too long for a comment) Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You can always call getRedirectResult. It would resolve with result. If `result.user` is null, then there is no sign in operation pending. You can then start the linking process. Otherwise, the user just completed sign in with redirect. You can then redirect to your signed in page.